# I can not get output from the seekbar

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar

I wanted the seekbar value outside the onProgressChanged method use But it always gives me a value of zero. I want to take the value of two seekbars and multiply them

```
class BmiActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    var weight =0f
    var height = 0f
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi)
    val seekbarHeight=findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBarHeight)

    var tvResultHeight=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResultHeight)
    val tvResultWeight=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResultWeight)
    val seekbarWeight =findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.seekBarWeight)
    val spinnerAge=findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerAge)
    val imageviewNeedle=findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewNeedle)
    val tvResultBmi=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewResultBmi)
    seekbarHeight.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            tvResultHeight.text=" "+progress.toString()
            height= progress.toFloat()
        }
        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
    seekbarWeight.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            tvResultWeight.text=" "+progress.toString()
            weight=progress.toFloat()
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
    var result = weight/(height*height)
    tvResultBmi.text=result.toString()
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do callback/interface. And then when both triggered, the value changed.

First, you need to create interface. Create a new file named ResultInterface.kt

```
interface ResultInterface {
    fun onValueChanged(height: Float, weight: Float)
}
```

And then put each of them to a function.

```
fun seekBarHeight(resultInterface: ResultInterface) {
        seekbarHeight.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                tvResultHeight.text = " " + progress.toString()
                val height = progress.toFloat()
                resultInterface.onValueChanged(height, 0f)
            }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
}


fun seekBarWeight(resultInterface: ResultInterface) {
        seekbarWeight.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                tvResultWeight.text = " " + progress.toString()
                val weight = progress.toFloat()
                resultInterface.onValueChanged(0f, weight)
            }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
}
```

Last, at your activity, implement the `ResutInterface`

```
class BmiActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ResultInterface {
```

After that you need to alt + enter . and the `onValueChanged` method will override.

```
  override fun onValueChanged(height: Float, weight: Float) {
        val result = weight/(height*height)
        tvResultBmi.text=result.toString()
    }
```